# How do I follow a dynamic file link to its home directory?

Tags: bash

```
>ls -alt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   67 Aug  3 10:49 myFile.txt -> /some/where/else/myFile.txt
```

i want to cd to

```
/some/where/else/
```

by typing something like

```
follow myFile.txt
```

does Unix have something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function:

```
follow () { cd $(dirname $(readlink -e "$1")); }
```